# C#: How to find the total sum of arrays inside functions?

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0

I have to create a function that enables me to enter data for every customer in a hardware store. The data that I should enter for every customer is: first name, last name, product bought and its price. This data should be stored in an array. Have this function declare a 1D container, have the user initialise this 1D container with the above data, and have the function return this 1D container back to MAIN. In MAIN, invoke this function three times to create data for  3 customers.

Afterwards, I need to create another function that takes all three 1D containers of customer data from MAIN as parameters and adds up all the prices of the products they bought. Have this function return the total cost back to MAIN. (This is where I'm stuck.)

Lastly, I need to create a procedure that takes the total cost returned to MAIN as parameter and figures out if this total price(set to a simple integer) is a prime number:

if the value is prime, print: "Customers win the Price"
otherwise, print: "Customers won't get the price"

I am stuck on the second function, I tried to do a C-style for loop, but it doesn't work.

I tried to add these three prices as array positions with indices but nothing.

This is the code I have:

```cs
using System;

namespace ghghh
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string [] inputData()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first name: ");
            string FirstName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your last name: ");
            string LastName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the product you ahve bought: ");
            string product = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the price: ");
            string price = Console.ReadLine();

            string[] info = new string[4] { FirstName, LastName, product, price };

            return info; 

        }

        public static void sumOfPrice(string[] arr)
        {
            

            for(int i = 0; i<arr.Length; i++)
            {
                string sum = arr[i] + arr[i] + arr[i];
            }


            
        }

        public static void isTotalCostPrime(int n)
        {
            if(n %2 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Customers wont get get the prize.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Customers win the prize");
            }
        }


        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            string[] final = inputData();
            sumOfPrice(final);
            

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is homework, so I'm not going to give you a solution.  Your code only allows the entry of a single purchased item.  Summing it is easy (`return price`).  What you probably want to do is create a type (a `class`) that contains the four properties you describe (first, last, product and price - with price being a `decimal`).  Then have a loop in `inputData` (by the way, the convention in C# is method names are written like this: `InputData`).  Add each class instance to a `List<YourClass>` (like an array, but stretchy - with an array you need to know how many items up front).

Comment: Once you get a collection of entries, calculating the sum is easy - just loop over the collection (using `foreach`) and sum the price properties.  I suggest you use `decimal.TryParse` to convert the entered string into a number (that way, you can re-prompt if someone enters `one dollar` instead of `1.00`).  Suggestions: 1) Fix your namespace. 2) `have` is spelled `have`, not `ahve`

Comment: Really confusing assignment. It seems to be suggesting that name, product, and price all be stored in the same "1D container," even though they are different data types. This is already a very strange design. Is the 1D container required to be an array? Seems to me a `Dictionary<string,object>` might make better sense. Do you have a choice?

Comment: Replying to Flydog57: Thanks. This isn't homework, it is a problem given by friends/classmates. We often give ourselves this kind of problems to stretch each other.

Comment: Replying to John Wu: Thanks for your reply. I can either use lists or arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a partial solution to your problem.  I made the prices decimal numbers (because most currencies are decimalized).  That precludes your *prime test* at the end.

I also included a quantity.  I was tempted to take out the first and last names for each item (since it requires a lot of typing).  All in all, though, this should give you enough to get started.

I start with a *POCO* class to hold the purchased items (POCO stands for "Plain Old CLR Object"; it's a class that consists purely of *properties*.  It's a bit like an old-fashioned C `struct`.

```
public class PurchasedItem
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

I separated the user interface out into a separate class (for reasons of *separation of concerns*).  You could easily collapse this into a single class:

```
public class ItemUserInterface
{
    public static PurchasedItem PromptForItem()
    {
        var purchasedItem = new PurchasedItem();
        Console.Write("What is your First Name (or type \"exit\" if complete)? > ");
        var firstName = Console.ReadLine();
        if (firstName.Equals("exit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return null;
        }
        purchasedItem.FirstName = firstName;
        Console.Write("What is your Last Name? > ");
        purchasedItem.LastName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("What did you purchase? > ");
        purchasedItem.ProductName = Console.ReadLine();
        purchasedItem.Quantity = PromptForInteger("How many did you buy");
        purchasedItem.Price = PromptForDecimal("What was the price");
        Console.WriteLine(""); //empty line
        return purchasedItem;
    }

    public static void ShowPurchase (PurchasedItem item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.FirstName} {item.LastName} bought {item.Quantity} of {item.ProductName} at {item.Price} each");
    }

    public static int PromptForInteger(string prompt)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write(prompt + " > ");
            var entered = Console.ReadLine();
            if (int.TryParse(entered, out var result))
            {
                return result;
            }
            //otherwise error
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, you must enter a proper integer value");
        }
    }

    public static decimal PromptForDecimal(string prompt)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write(prompt + " > ");
            var entered = Console.ReadLine();
            if (decimal.TryParse(entered, out var result))
            {
                return result;
            }
            //otherwise error
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, you must enter a proper decimal value");
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, `while (true)` will loop forever unless you do something like `return` or `break` out of the loop.  Notice that I prompt the user over and over again until he/she enters a correctly formatted number (for the number entries).

Finally, here's my `Main` routine:

```
var itemsList = new List<PurchasedItem>();
while (true)
{
    var item = ItemUserInterface.PromptForItem();
    if (item == null)
    {
        break;
    }
    itemsList.Add(item);
}

// at this point, everything is entered
var totalPurchasePrice = 0.00m;
var totalItemsCount = 0;

foreach (var item in itemsList)
{
    ItemUserInterface.ShowPurchase(item);
    totalPurchasePrice += (item.Quantity * item.Price);
    totalItemsCount += item.Quantity;
}

Console.WriteLine($"Purchase Summary: {itemsList.Count} different items ({totalItemsCount} total items) for {totalPurchasePrice:C}");
Console.ReadLine(); //pause
```

}

If I run this program the output looks like:

```
What is your First Name (or type "exit" if complete)? > Fly
What is your Last Name? > Dog57
What did you purchase? > Cabbage
How many did you buy > 2
What was the price > 1.99

What is your First Name (or type "exit" if complete)? > Fly
What is your Last Name? > Dog57
What did you purchase? > Hammer
How many did you buy > 6
What was the price > abc
Sorry, you must enter a proper decimal value
What was the price > 10.55

What is your First Name (or type "exit" if complete)? > exit
Fly Dog57 bought 2 of Cabbage at 1.99 each
Fly Dog57 bought 6 of Hammer at 10.55 each
Purchase Summary: 2 different items (8 total items) for $67.28
```